# Matplotlib Subplots Unexpected Float Number on X-Y Axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Matplotlib to plot two transposed bar plots side by side. However, I got some unexpected floating numbers overlapped with major tick labels on the x-y axes. These float numbers are 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0. Some of these numbers are overlapped with the major tick labels. Do you know how to get rid of these unwanted tiny float numbers: 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0?

Here is the image. I highlight those unwanted float numbers in red boxes.
[image]

Here is the code.

```
action_number = [5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
action_list = ['DrawSword', 'Kiss', 'RideBike', 'Dribble', 'Hug', 'Dive', 
               'Cartwheel', 'Drink', 'Climb', 'Eat', 'Walk', 'FallFloor', 
               'Stand', 'Sword', 'Pick', 'SwingBaseb', 'Handstand', 'ShootBow']

def bar_plot(action_list, action_number, ax):
    y_pos = np.arange(len(action_list))

    ax.barh(y_pos, action_number, height=0.75, align='center', color='b')
    ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
    ax.set_yticklabels(action_list)

    ax.invert_yaxis()

    ax.tick_params(labelsize=12, which='both', axis='both')

    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

    plt.autoscale(tight=True)
    plt.tight_layout()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
bar_plot(action_list, action_number, ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
bar_plot(action_list, action_number, ax2)
plt.savefig('action_attribute_sidebyside.pdf',bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through. Have you tried removing it bit-by-bit to find where the problem arises? At the very least, you should be able to come up with a much smaller block of code to show here

Comment: `ax1.set_yticks(y_pos);ax1.set_yticklabels(action_list)`I think the two lines of code in question are these two lines of code, but what does the data look like for each?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have updated the code and image.

Comment: You're creating 2 sets of axes. Remove both lines which have `fig.add_subplot` in and it should work

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution. It perfectly works!

Answer (score 0):

```py
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import random
    
    action_number = [5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    action_list = ['DrawSword', 'Kiss', 'RideBike', 'Dribble', 'Hug', 'Dive',
                   'Cartwheel', 'Drink', 'Climb', 'Eat', 'Walk', 'FallFloor',
                   'Stand', 'Sword', 'Pick', 'SwingBaseb', 'Handstand', 'ShootBow']
    
    
    def random_color():
        return "#%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
    
    
    colors = [random_color() for x in action_list]
    
    
    def auto_label(horizontal_):
        for index, rectangle in enumerate(horizontal_):
            height = rectangle.get_height()
            width = rectangle.get_width()
            y_value = rectangle.get_y()
            plt.text(width + height/2., y_value, "%d" % width, color=colors[index])
    
    
    plt.subplot(121)
    horizontal = plt.barh(action_list, action_number, edgecolor="k", color=colors)
    auto_label(horizontal)
    
    plt.subplot(122)
    horizontal = plt.barh(action_list, action_number, edgecolor="k", color=colors)
    auto_label(horizontal)
    
    plt.grid()
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I would suggest you to have a look at [this](https://github.com/Weilory/python-matplotlib-graphs) which are a variety of easy graphics with code example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I still have no idea of how to incorporate your solution into my code. Could you please offer more hint? Thanks!

Comment: @ZhenyuWu Please have a look, I have modified

Comment: This is amazing. I have stared and forked your fantastic code.